# issue retrieve json data in swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I have issue that I can't retrieving json data in swift, I kept getting error message 
[image: this image describe the issue I have.]

```
var url = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!
    var data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
    do {
        jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(withData: data, options: .allowFragments)!
    }
    catch let error {
    }
```

I was working with Objective C but I want to switch to Swift language

Comment: let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(validData, options: options)

Comment: @MikeAlter I have tried this before and still not working

Comment: Your app will certainly crash if an error occurs in the `do - catch` block. You cannot simply continue after the catch part.

Comment: @vadian I'm getting error before the app crush, I have tried many codes but still not working for me at all

Comment: You should make clear that you are talking about Swift 3.

Comment: @vadian I know that but I want first receive data from my json file then thinking about that issue

Comment: The Information **Swift 3** is crucial to get the right signature. I edited the tags.

Comment: Have you tried : let jsonArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

Comment: @CRDave yes but still getting error :(

Comment: Same error or different?

Comment: @CRDave Of course different error ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks, please use the **code completion** feature to find the proper syntax

When you type `JSONSerialization.` you will see

[image]

The appropriate method is

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options: .allowFragments)
```

Or press <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd> (zero not O) and look up the method in the documentation by typing or pasting the class. Every developer must be able to read the documentation.

Aside from that you have to cast the result of the deserialization to the expected type

```
jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String:Any]]
```

Comment: yes I have tried it before and still not working at all

Comment: Basically this code works. You will get other errors. I updated the answer to resolve one.

Comment: I'm getting "Ambigouus reference member 'jsonObject(with:options)' error

Comment: `data` is an optional. You need to unwrap it. By the way you should use the new native types: `let url = URL(string: getDataURL)!` `let data = Data(contentsOf: url)!` But you are strongly discouraged from using synchronous methods like `Data(contentsOf:` because they block the thread.

Comment: Write `let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)!` and put it in the `do` block

Answer (score 0):

Try this code send request and get data.

```
 if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(fooData!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
 {
        print(jsonResult)
  }else{
         return failure(NSError)
 }
```

Comment: @YousefAbuSallamah in fooData pass your Data

Comment: This is Swift 2, the question is about Swift 3.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya It seem like you and OP are on different Swift version.

Comment: @vadian xcode will replace code from swift 2 to swift 3

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I'm getting error swift compiler now after adding your code